# Instance limited cron job

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I want to run a cron job every minute that will launch a script. Simple enough there. However, I need to make sure that not more than X number (defined in the script) of instances are ever running. These are queue workers, so if at any minute interval 6 workers are still active, then I would not launch another instance. The script simply launches a PHP script which exits if no job available. Right now I have a shell script that perpetually launches itself every 10 seconds after exit... but there are long periods of time where there are no jobs, and a minute delay is fine. Eventually I would like to have two cron jobs for peak and off-peak, with different intervals.

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I_want_to_process_a_bunch_of_files_in_parallel.2C_and_when_one_finishes.2C_I_want_to_start_the_next._And_I_want_to_make_sure_there_are_exactly_5_jobs_running_at_a_time.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have unique script name.
2. Then check if 6 instances are already running

   ```
   if [ $(pgrep '^UNIQUE_SCIPT_NAME$' -c) -lt 6 ]
   then 
       # start my script
   else
       # do not start my script
   fi
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that if you want to iterate as often as every minute, then a process like your current shell script that relaunches itself is what you actually want to do. Just increase the delay from 10 seconds to a minute.

That way, you can also more easily control your delay for peak and off-peak, as you wanted. It would be rather elegant to simply use a shorter delay if the script found something to do the last time it was launched, or a longer delay if it did not find anything.

Comment: hmm... i like that idea of a success-based delay... will have to try that

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script like [OneAtATime](https://github.com/ldo/OneAtATime) to guard against multiple simultaneous executions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i am using in my shell scripts:

```
echo -n "Checking if job is already running... "
me=`basename $0`
running=$(ps aux | grep ${me} | grep -v .log | grep -v grep | wc -l)
if [ $running -gt 1 ];
then
    echo "already running, stopping job"
    exit 1
else
    echo "OK."
fi;
```

The command you're looking for is in line 3. Just replace `$(me)` with your php script name. In case you're wondering about the `grep .log` part: I'm piping the output into a log file, whose name partially contains the script name, so this way i'm avoiding it to be double-counted.